# Freeman-halton simple examples?

Tags: fishers-exact-test

Does anyone know where I can see a step by step simple example of the Fisher-Freeman-Halton equation? I am a developer so need to build the process from scratch and have already done so for the Fisher part but now need to extend it to x n possibilities. Wikipedia has a good example for the basic version but not the more complex.

I have found https://www.statsdirect.co.uk/help/chi_square_tests/rc.htm but its not particularly clear.

Answer (score 0):

Hidden away under "Formulas" at the bottom of https://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc/calculator.aspx?id=59 is a good starting point!